# Probability of the intersection of the complement of two events

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are events for which $P(A)=x, P(B)=y$, and $P(A\cap B)=z.$ Express the following probability in terms of $x, y, \text{and} \,z$. $P(\bar A\cup \bar B$).

Answer: $1-z$.

This is the Exercise 1.16 from (Paul Meyer, "Introductory Probability and Statistical Applications", 2ed)

My attempt:

$P(\bar A\cup \bar B) = P(\bar A) + P(\bar B) - P(\bar A\cap \bar B)$

$\qquad=1-x +1-y-[(1-x)(1-y)]$

$\qquad=2-x-y-[1-y-x+xy]$

$\qquad=1-xy$

What was my mistake here? I don't get why $z$ appeared in the answer since we are taking the interjection between the complement events of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: You defined the probability of the intersection in terms of the probability of the intersection! it is should be $$P(\overline{A}\cup \overline{B}) = P(\overline{A})+P(\overline{B})-P(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B})$$

Comment: Why you used? $P(\overline{A}\cap\overline{B}) = P(\overline{A})P(\overline{B})$ thats only true if they are independent events

Comment: @IrbidMath Misspelling there, my bad.

Comment: Are you familiar with DeMorgan's laws?

Comment: @IrbidMath Didn't knew that could be used only on independent events, and nothing else came up to mind.

Comment: @IrbidMath Never heard of. In this textbook that I'm using he only covers an introduction to probability and some set theory in this chapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in one of the comments, no information is given about whether $A,B$ are independent events.  Therefore, there is insufficient information to compute (for example)

$$p(A \cap B).$$

The intended solution is that you are supposed to recognize that if you have two events $E_1,E_2$ that are complementary, that $p(E_1) + p(E_2) = 1.$  By complementary events, I intend that the two events are mutually exclusive and that you are guaranteed that exactly one of the two events has occurred.

Then, the point of the problem is to recognize that

the events $(A \cap B)$ and $[\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}]$ are complementary events.

That is, either it is the case that events $A$ and $B$ both occur, or it is not the case that events $A$ and $B$ both occur.

The 2nd scenario above, that it is not the case that events $A$ and $B$ both occur is equivalent to the assertion that **either** the event $\overline{A}$ occurred or the event $\overline{B}$ occurred.